# Characters between < and > are not able to display in datalist

Tags: asp.net, label, datalist

In my textbox the characters i am entering between < and > are not displaying in datalist control.For example i am entering  in textbox, and the data is saved in database.But when i am calling the function to get the data from database,value is coming from database but it  is not displaying in datalist label control.ther special characters it is showing but except characters like .

But i want  in a string how to find the full string & replace < with < and > with > in the entire string.For eg it we are entering  in textbox then while saving to database it should be saved as <fff> in asp .net.lease give me an example

Comment: HTML escape the values

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what asp is doing with the datalist control but it's definitely outputting it to html. And in html "<" and ">" are special characters. Write a method to replace those special characters. E.g. "<" will be &lt; and > will be &gt;

A reference to special characters in html:

http://www.degraeve.com/reference/specialcharacters.php

Answer (score 0):

I am not an asp developer but I googled the synonym of htmlentities to asp.. Use HtmlEncode()